# At canEditRowAtIndexPath Method, reloadData of UITableView not work properly?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my application, I reload my TableView *(`[tablView reloadData];`)* after delete row from TableView then `canEditRowAtIndexPath` Method alway call for **(pervious)** total number Of Rows.

**For Example:**

If i have **5** Rows on my TableView, then i delete **1** row from tableView. After deleting, I **reload** my TableView *(`[tablView reloadData]`)* but `canEditRowAtIndexPath` Method calls **5 time**  instead of **4 times** ??

So i always got Following **Error:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', **reason:** '*** **-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'**

I also tried to reload table after some delay (using `NSTimer`) but it also not worked for me.

**I put some code here:**

I apply `canEditRowAtIndexPath` on specific row which `@"status" isEqualToString:@"directory"` such like,

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%d", self.listOfSounds.count);
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    if([[[self.listOfSounds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"directory"])
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Code of delete row:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self.sql_ deleteSoundFileAudioTableWhereMainID:[[self.listOfSounds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"main_id"]]; /// delete record from DB
        [self.listOfSounds removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; /// delete record from Array
        [self updateListofSoundsFile]; /// Custom method
    }
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO; // i also tried to  return YES;
}
```

Here `updateListofSoundsFile` is my custom method code is :

```
-(void)updateListofSoundsFile
{
    if(self.listOfSounds.count > 0)
        [self.listOfSounds removeAllObjects];

    self.listOfSounds = [self.sql_ getAllDataFromAudioTable]; // get all record from DB
    NSLog(@"%d",self.listOfSounds.count);

    [self.tblView reloadData];  
}
```

Please Give any suggestion, How can i solve this issue ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Post your `numberOfRowsInSection` method. Question - In your `commitEditingStyle` method, why do you call `updateListOfSoundsFile`?  You already update `listOfSounds` by removing one object. After removing the object from the array, just call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` to remove one row from the table. Also verify that your call to `deleteSoundFileAudioTableWhereMainID` is actually removing one row from the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to remove raw from tableview also befor remove item from array and reload data using this line becouse remove item from array but not tableview.

`[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self.sql_ deleteSoundFileAudioTableWhereMainID:[[self.listOfSounds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"main_id"]]; /// delete record from DB

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.listOfSounds removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; /// delete record from Array

        [self updateListofSoundsFile]; /// Custom method
    }
}
```

Comment: This should not be the solution. 1 - you should always remove the data from the data source before updating the table. 2 - If you are going to call `reloadData`, there is no reason at all to first call `deleteRowsAtIndexPath:`. This solution may work but it is hiding some other issue.

Comment: then please guide us what's the proper solution sir please put answer with proper solution. thank's

Comment: @rmaddy- sir, if you have other best solution then please guide us, for improve knowledge. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem. The issue was that I deleted the object of the cell but when I used the `reloadData` method of the `tableView`, my `canEditRowAtIndexPath` method was not being called resulting in being able to edit cells that I do not want edited. The true fix was not calling the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` method, but the `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];` method.

Basically here is what was happening:

When I called `reloadData`:
The raw data was not being removed from the `tableView` as Nitin said. Therefore this is not the solution.

When I called `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`:
iOS detected a discrepancy between the underlying data and the number of cells (because I had already removed the underlying object). The result was a crash which is also not the solution (obviously).

Now for The Fix!

When I called `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`:
This caused the tableView to simply reload that single cell AND it got rid of the raw data. This is the solution.

Rather than removing the `dataSource` object, then trying to remove the cell that is essentially backed by nothing at this point (which causes a crash), simply remove the `dataSource` object, then reload that `indexPath` of the `tableView`

Here is the general format of the method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [myDataSourceArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}
```

This is the first time I ran into the issue with the residual raw data that is not removed by simply calling the `reloadData` method. This is certainly the most elegant solution that I have seen thus far.

Happy Coding! I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self.sql_ deleteSoundFileAudioTableWhereMainID:[[self.listOfSounds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"main_id"]]; /// delete record from DB
        [self.listOfSounds removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; /// delete record from Array
        [self updateListofSoundsFile]; /// Custom method
    }
   [self.tblView reloadData]; 
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves the problem? The `updateListofSoundsFile` method already calls `reloadData`.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to me, I analysed as below:

As commented by `rmaddy` on `Nitin Gohel's` answer:

1. You should always remove the data from the data source before updating the table.

   I feels this is the ideal way.
2. If you are going to call `reloadData`, there is no reason at all to first call `deleteRowsAtIndexPath`.

   This is also looks correct.

I analysed ambiguity, if I write `reloadData` its crashishing but once I write  `deleteRowsAtIndexPath` it worked well.

Hope someone will emphasise on this issue for its causes etc.

Answer (score 0):

the 'removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath' takes some time and I suspect your **[self.tblView reloadData]** is being called early. I tried a sample code and found success with **[UiTableView beginUpdates]** and **[UiTableView endUpdates]** you may also avoid crash if you put a little delay before the reloading or deleting rows haven't tried it though

```
[tableTable beginUpdates];
[tableArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tableTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableTable endUpdates];
```