# Delete button remains displayed when using commitEditingStyle (cf gif)

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I'm trying to delete a `UITableviewCell` with a swipe gesture.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

{
    return YES;
}
```

With

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

           [_commentsData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           _NBComment--;

           [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

       }

}
```

The result is this:

[image]

The delete buttons remains displayed after the row deletion.

Do you have an idea to make the row deletion smoother?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Don't ask me why, but this code works:

```
[_commentsData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
_NBComment--;
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView setEditing:NO animated:NO];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this code after deletion:

```
[tableview reloadData];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in fact this code is written in order to avoid using `reloadData`.

When I use reloadData after deletion, I have a crash (cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394816/at-caneditrowatindexpath-method-reloaddata-of-uitableview-not-work-properly)